# Gives Internal Server Error while trying to access to the contoller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I trying to access my Rental Controller but it gives me internal error. It was working fine before some changes ( i don't rememember them).Also other controllers(e.g BrandController) are working fine now.

**RentalsController**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RentalsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IRentalService _rentalService;

        public RentalsController(IRentalService rentalService)
        {
            _rentalService = rentalService;
        }

        [HttpGet("getall")]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var result = _rentalService.GetAllRentals();

            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }

            return BadRequest(result);
        }
```

**BrandsController**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BrandsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBrandService _brandService;

        public BrandsController(IBrandService brandService)
        {
            _brandService = brandService;   
        }

        [HttpGet("getall")]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var result = _brandService.GetAllBrands();

            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }

            return BadRequest(result);
        }
```

**AutofacBusinessModule**

```
    public class AutofacBusinessModule :Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
              
            builder.RegisterType<BrandManager>().As<IBrandService>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<EfBrandDal>().As<IBrandDal>().SingleInstance();
                       
            builder.RegisterType<RentalManager>().As<IRentalService>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<EfRentalDal>().As<IRentalDal>().SingleInstance();
```

***Update***

Broswer output
[image]

When i trigger thewhen I triggered the function, the output gives an error as follows.

**Output**

```
The thread 0x1b64 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
The thread 0x3780 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4cbc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Have you analyzed the **Output** window? Do you get notable errors there?

Comment: Please show more error detail for us.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put output, please check it again

Comment: Please add breakpoint in your method and debug it. You can update your post with the exception. You also can use try...catch... to find the exception message.